# How to sort by keys if they contain non-Latin characters?

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

My first file contains the following text:

```
γβα
αγβ
βαγ
```

I want to sort the lines in the alphabetical order, so I use the following command:

```
sort -t'|' -f -i path/to/input1.txt > path/to/output1.txt
```

Then I get the following output:

```
αγβ
βαγ
γβα
```

So the command seems to work as expected (with the non-Latin characters). Then my second file contains the following text:

```
1|γβα
2|αγβ
3|βαγ
```

I want to sort it by the second column in the alphabetical order, so I use the following command:

```
sort -t'|' -f -i -k2 path/to/input2.txt > path/to/output2.txt
```

Then I get the following output:

```
1|γβα
2|αγβ
3|βαγ
```

But the expected output is

```
2|αγβ
3|βαγ
1|γβα
```

The `locale` command shows

```
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Then I added

```
LANG="en_US.utf8"
export LANG
```

to the `.bash_profile` file. Now the `locale` command shows

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

The `file -bi path/to/input2.txt` command shows

```
text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So I executed the second command again:

```
sort -t'|' -f -i -k2 path/to/input2.txt > path/to/output2.txt
```

But the output is the same:

```
1|γβα
2|αγβ
3|βαγ
```

Why doesn't the second command work as expected? How to sort by keys in the alphabetical order if they contain non-Latin characters? How to explain the fact that the sorting is correct when I don’t specify the key?

Comment: I get the expected output using the same command line. What's your locale setting? Run the `locale` command and show the output.

Comment: What character encoding is the file using? I have a feeling it's not utf-8.

Comment: (If I convert the data from UTF-8 to [ISO-8859-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7) for example and try to sort that when using a UTF-8 locale I get the same order you do)

Answer (score 0):

The `C.UTF-8` locale does not support sorting non-ASCII code points. Try `en_US.UTF-8` (which works for me).

Comment: If the `C.UTF-8` locale does not support sorting non-ASCII code points, then why do I get the correct output for the first file?